# Access a variable from inside ajax call success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following in my js file:

```
var highestNumb;
$.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.m.hostelworld.com/1.5/properties/'+propID+'/?update-cache=true', 
          dataType: 'json', 
          headers: {
            "Accept-Language": lang 
          },
          success: function(json) { 
            var numb = 0;
            for (var key in json.rating) {
                numb = Math.max(numb, json.rating[key]);
            }
            highestNumb = numb;
            return highestNumb;

          }, cache: false
});
var enH3 = 'Fellow travellers have rated this property ' + highestNumb + ' out of 100.',
    deH3 = 'Gäste haben das Hostel mit ' + highestNumb + ' von 100 Punkten bewertet. ',
    frH3 = 'Les autres voyageurs ont classé cette propriété ' + highestNumb + ' sur 100',
    esH3 = 'Otros viajeros han puntuado este alojamiento con u ' + highestNumb + ' sobre 100.',
    itH3 = "I tuoi compagni di viaggio hanno recensito questa struttura " + highestNumb + " su 100",
    brH3 = 'Hóspedes anteriores avaliaram esta propriedade em ' + highestNumb + ' de 100.',
    ptH3 = 'Hóspedes anteriores avaliaram esta propriedade em ' + highestNumb + ' de 100.',
    koH3 = '직접 여행한 숙박객들은 이 호스텔을 10점 만점 중 XX점 주셨습니다. ';
```

I am getting undefined every time I pass "highestNumber" in the variables translation below.

Am I accessing the variable in the wrong way?

Comment: Are you doing it `async:false` way ? OR you did not consider that `AJAX` is asynchronous ?

Answer (score 3):

You should in your success function call another function, eg. setVars(highestNumb) and put your code that sets enH3, deH3 etc. variables in that function.

```
success: function(json) { 
   //your code
   setVars(numb);
}

function setVars(highestNumb)
{
    enH3 = 'Fellow travellers have rated this property ' + highestNumb + ' out of 100.';
    //....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please put async:false

var highestNumb;
$.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.m.hostelworld.com/1.5/properties/'+propID+'/?update-cache=true', 
          dataType: 'json', 
          async:false,
          headers: {
            "Accept-Language": lang 
          },
          success: function(json) { 
            var numb = 0;
            for (var key in json.rating) {
                numb = Math.max(numb, json.rating[key]);
            }
            highestNumb = numb;
            return highestNumb;

```
      }, cache: false
```

});

Comment: __Please NEVER put async:false__

Comment: Synchronous requests are deprecated. Do not use them.